# Reduction formula to $\sin^n(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, reduction-formula

What would be the integral of $\sin^n(x)$ under the limits $0$ and $\pi/2$, using reduction formula?
I've got :

$$I(n) = \frac{n-1}{n}I(n-2)$$

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, it's right.

Comment: @LeBlanc Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to have an answer to the question: Yes, it is right.

Comment: @Leucippus Sorry, but this does provide an answer to the question. The question was about the correctness of the answer of the op. And because it was already answered in the comments, so I made a community wiki answer just to make it clear, because not everyone reads the comments.